# Duplicated Entry message when copy rows from old table to new table

Tags: mysql

I open a table each month automatically and I pass rows of some table of the last month, I perform the query thrown me a message "Duplicate Entry" I'm trying to understand why this happens if the table I re-create is entirely new, which I noticed all the new row in the table gets Incremental ID to ID last, written in my table however is the fact that nextindex index plus one index was the previous table.
I enclose the code I am building with the table, and the query against the data structure, would love to get advice where I'm wrong.
**I will summarize the problems:**

1) Open the new table, but the ID is incremental to the ID of the previous table, just does not make sense if I write AUTO-INCREMENT 1 when creating a new table.

2) queries against the DATABASE gives me an error

3) there is a connection to the nextautoindex, I need to reset him?

Peice of code:
**Mysql Query**

```
insert into gyoman072013 (pnumber,id,MokedCcode,WCODE,ndate,TIMECALL,EventHandling,Endtimecare,User,TIMEARRIAVAL,FREEDATA,sendtime) select gyoman062013.pnumber,gyoman062013.id,gyoman062013.MokedCcode,gyoman062013.WCODE,gyoman062013.ndate,gyoman062013.TIMECALL,gyoman062013.EventHandling,gyoman062013.Endtimecare,gyoman062013.User,gyoman062013.TIMEARRIAVAL,gyoman062013.FREEDATA,gyoman062013.sendtime from gyoman062013 RIGHT JOIN eventcodes ON gyoman062013.WCODE=eventcodes.WCODE AND eventcodes.PRIORITY='1' where EventHandling!='2'
```

Note: I think there is no problem with my query ( maybe ) but the problem cause from the table structure I re-create every month.

**Table Structure Query:**

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gyoman".$datestamp." (
 `pnumber` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `MokedCcode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `GroupB` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `WCODE` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `ndate` date NOT NULL,
 `TIMECALL` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `EventHandling` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `Endtimecare` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `User` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `TIMEARRIAVAL` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `FREEDATA` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `sendtime` time NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `MokedCcode` (`MokedCcode`),
  KEY `WCODE` (`WCODE`),
  KEY `GroupB` (`GroupB`),
  KEY `ndate` (`ndate`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1"
```

Note: datestamp is the cureent month, you can see @ my query.
Thanks!.

Comment: I don't know if I am getting this clearly. What you are saying is every time you create a new table it's first value of the primary key would continue with value of the table where it was copied? Like OldTable last value is 100 so when you create a new table the auto increment value goes to 101? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes, this is one of the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried using ALTER TABLE to explicitly reset the auto increment to 1 like ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; Although I see you're putting auto increment to 1 there. But just try after the table is created using ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Please reduce (and format) your SQL to the absolute minimum required to show the problem. Ie delete from the question *most* of your columns. Ideally, create an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and show desired output. Also, (more) clearly state what your problem/question is

Comment: Did you take a look at the resultset and checked for duplicates of your select without inserting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the `AUTO INCREMENT` after the table is created like:

```
ALTER TABLE gyoman072013 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: I did that but there is no change.

Comment: OK, In addition your answer I realized that my query have duplicated rows somehow, I add after the SELECT DISTINCT and its cause that the result will be with no duplicated id so its solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it works for your @OfirAttia. So, it was a "duplicate entry" after all. Happy coding and GOD bless.